# What is the right context for using tf.contrib.lookup and tf.python.ops.lookup_ops?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know that `tf.contrib.lookup` and `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops` include the same functions. But is there any difference between using  `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file` and `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops.index_table_from_file`? I came across the code using `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops.index_table_from_file` in the [seq2seq tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/blob/master/nmt/utils/vocab_utils.py), so I am wondering why not use `tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_file` instead? If I want to use it in my code, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, [`tensorflow.contrib.lookup.lookup_ops.*` being simply imported as-is in `tf.contrib.lookup`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/__init__.py#L48).

Use `tf.contrib.lookup.*` rather than `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops.*`, not only because it is shorter, but simply because the former is part of the official python API, and not the later.

As for why they used `tf.python.ops.lookup_ops.index_table_from_file` directly in the example you provide, I am not sure. Maybe they felt that a file named `utils/vocab_utils.py` is an "internal" thing that they own and that could by-pass the public API. Not a practice to import into your own code IMHO.